# How to pass `&dyn T` to a function that accepts `impl T`?

Tags: rust, dynamic-dispatch

In this example, the function `foo` only accepts `a` as argument. If changed to accept `&dyn Trait`, it would only accept `b` as argument and not `a`.

```rust
trait Trait {}

fn foo<T: Trait>(_: T) {}

fn demo(a: impl Trait, b: &dyn Trait) {
    foo(a);
    foo(b);
}
```

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&dyn Trait: Trait` is not satisfied
 --> src/lib.rs:7:9
  |
3 | fn foo<T: Trait>(_: T) {}
  |           ----- required by this bound in `foo`
...
7 |     foo(b);
  |         ^ the trait `Trait` is not implemented for `&dyn Trait`
```

Is there a way such that a function would be able to accept both `a` and `b` as an argument?

Comment: [Applying the duplicate to your situation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c4bf0e7d4594e6c82ef2334047bd9091): `impl Trait for &'_ dyn Trait {}` (or the more generic `impl<T: Trait + ?Sized> Trait for &'_ T {}`)

Comment: @tadman treating a trait object as an implementer of a trait is pretty common. I expect you’ve called a method from `Iterator` on a `Box<dyn Iterator>`